# jQuery Each Loop is triggering if statement on each loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jQuery each loop that is looking for everything with the class `.big-box-300x250` on my page and appending a number of ad scripts for Google DFP.

What I want to occur is that if the containing div has an iFrame it should trigger the if statement and set the parents height. The problem I'm having is that each time the script loops it always triggers the if statement and doesn't seem to be selective about what it hides and shows.

```
    $('.big-box-300x250').each(function(index) {
        var display = $(this).data("desktop-display");
        if (display == true){

          var feedData = $(this).data('ad-type');
          var ad_script = '<script type="text/javascript">googletag.cmd.push(function() { googletag.display("' + feedData + '"); });</script>';
          $(this).append(ad_script);

            if ($(this).has('iframe')) {
                console.log("Triggering");
                $(this).parent().height(250)
                $(this).parent().css("margin", "20px 0")
                $(this).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

The data pulled in from the feedData variable is unique, and also utilized for the ID too. For example the div might look something like this:

```
<div id="div-gpt-ad-1450382754763-1" class="pb-ad-container big-box-300x250 border-bottom-hairline" data-mobile-display="false" data-desktop-display="true" data-ad-type="div-gpt-ad-1450382754763-1" style="">
```

How can I fix this script so on every loop it looks at each ad div individually, determines if it has an iFrame, and then runs the script accordingly before going onto the next one.

This is what the generated markup looks like. The top two are working ads, and the second one is an empty ad with no content. The top two are the ones I want to trigger the if statement on, however it triggers on all of them.

[image]

Comment: Do you have any elements with class `big-box-300x250` that are nested inside other elements with class `big-box-300x250`?

Comment: @MattBrowne Negative. There are multiple items with big-box-300x250 on the page, but they are not nested within each other.

Answer (score 1):

Here you should check if the `.length` `is >0`, because `.has()` method doesn't return `boolean` value

```
 if ($(this).has('iframe').length>0) {
```

Comment: don't even need the `>0` part ... length can be used as boolean

Comment: Yes. Just for some additional clarification (now that I understand the issue)...the return value of `has()` will always be a jQuery object (even if it's an empty one), so it will always evaluate to true.

Comment: @ Matt Browne exactly

Comment: Strangely this still doesn't seem to do the trick. It doesn't fire the if statement, even on a timeout. Although one thing I have noticed is that the script seems to generate two iFrames. An empty one within (this) and a second one made within a containing div. What would be the best way to select that? $(this).find("div").has("iframe").length > 0 ?

Comment: I also attached a screenshot of the markup in case that helps.

Comment: $(this).find("iframe") as I can't see where the second one is

Comment: Not sure then. It triggers regardless if $(this) has an iFrame within it or not. I ran a console log on this within the if statement and this is what it prints: http://i.stack.imgur.com/VGhyQ.png

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if ($(this).has('iframe').length)
```